# How do i skip every 1000 rows in API request API using Python with data source is e-conomic

Tags: python, json, pandas, python-requests, openpyxl

I am trying to collect data from from e-conomic.dk, but the API will only let me retrieve 1000 rows per call, so I think I need to create a list indicating 1 row for every 1000 rows in the datasource. After that I need a logic that skips the first 1000 rows if already retrieved and then continue to retrieve the next 1000 rows etc.

API doc: https://restdocs.e-conomic.com/#endpoints

This is my Python code:

```
#This code calls the ENTRIES API from e-conomic and sends data to SQL
#API doc = https://restdocs.e-conomic.com/ 

import requests
import json
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy.engine as sqle

HEADERS = {         
    "X-AgreementGrantToken": "demo",
        "X-AppSecretToken": "demo",
        }

def get_api_data(endpoint):
    url = "https://restapi.e-conomic.com"

    query = {
        "pagesize": "1000",
        "skippages": str(0)
    }
    response = requests.get(f'{url}/{endpoint}', headers = HEADERS, params = {**query})
    data = response.json()
    return data

def get_db_engine():
    conn_str = "DRIVER={SQL SERVER};SERVER=JAKOB-MSI;DATABASE=MightyMonday;TRUSTED_CONNECTION=yes"
    conn_url = sqle.URL.create("mssql+pyodbc", query = {'odbc_connect': conn_str})
    engine = sqle.create_engine(conn_url)

    return engine

source = get_api_data("accounting-years")
collection = source["collection"]
# print(source)
entries = pd.DataFrame(collection)

res = requests.get(entries['entries'][0] + '?skippages=0&pagesize=30', headers = HEADERS)
data = res.json()

dataset = pd.DataFrame(data['collection'])
dataset['accountNumber'] = [d.get('accountNumber') for d in dataset.account]
dataset = dataset[['accountNumber', 'amountInBaseCurrency', 'date', 'text']]

#Change the target SQL table here
dataset.to_sql('Entries_demo_values', con = get_db_engine(), if_exists = 'replace', index = False)
```

This is a fully functional M code written using PowerBI that skips the rows as intended.

```
let
    function1 = (EndPoint as text, PagesToSkip as number) =>
    let 
        Url = "https://restapi.e-conomic.com",
        Headers = [#"X-AgreementGrantToken"="demo", #"X-AppSecretToken"="demo"],
        Query = [pagesize = "1000", skippages = Text.From(PagesToSkip)],

        data = Json.Document(Web.Contents(Url, [Headers = Headers, Query = Query, RelativePath = EndPoint]))

    in data,

    function2 = (tal) => List.Generate(()=>0, each _ <= tal, each _ +1),

    Source = function1("accounts", 0),
    collection = Source[collection],
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(collection, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"accountNumber", "accountType", "balance", "blockDirectEntries", "debitCredit", "name", "accountingYears", "self", "vatAccount", "totalFromAccount", "openingAccount", "accountsSummed"}, {"accountNumber", "accountType", "balance", "blockDirectEntries", "debitCredit", "name", "accountingYears", "self", "vatAccount", "totalFromAccount", "openingAccount", "accountsSummed"}),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Expanded Column1",{"accountNumber", "accountType", "name"}),
    #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "KontoOverskrift", each if [accountType] = "heading" then [name] else null),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Conditional Column",{"KontoOverskrift"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Filled Down",{{"accountNumber", Int64.Type}, {"accountType", type text}, {"name", type text}, {"KontoOverskrift", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

With the this Python code I am able to retrieve the data and send to Excel. But the skip 1000 rows logic explained above

```
#This code calls the account API from e-conomic and writes a Excel file with the data

import requests
import json
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd

def Function1(endpoint):
    url = "https://restapi.e-conomic.com"
    headers = {
        "X-AgreementGrantToken": "demo",
        "X-AppSecretToken": "demo",
    }
    query = {
        "pagesize": "1000",
        "skippages": str(0)
    }
    response = requests.get(f'{url}/{endpoint}', headers = headers, params = {**query})
    data = response.json()
    return data

def function2(tal):
    return range(0, tal+1)

source = Function1("accounts")

# source = function1("accounts", 0)
collection = source["collection"]

dataset = pd.DataFrame(collection)
data = dataset[['accountNumber','accountType','name']]

data.to_excel('AccountDataAuto.xlsx', index = False)
```

Comment: sorry,I don't quite follow along - skip 1000 rows. I think your first query would be `query = {
    "pagesize": "1000",
    "skippages": str(0)
}` i.e give first 1000 records, then `query = {
    "pagesize": "1000",
    "skippages": str(1)
}` give next 1000 records, and you can loop through the above logic, i.e. keep on increasing `skippages` ,  Thank for detailed question, will plus 1 for that :)